# How to remove aws elasticache redis type cluster using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elasticache

I want to remove an aws elasticache redis cluster using boto3.

The syntax I was expecting to work was:

```
response = client.delete_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='string'
)
```

But it does not work. In fact, the documentation states:

> This operation is not valid for:
>
> - Redis (cluster mode enabled) clusters

I'm not able to find how can I delete the redis cluster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Redis only command, `delete_replication_group`. See [This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.delete_replication_group).

---

Once you find the doc. for `create_replication_group`, then it says

> Creates a Redis (cluster mode disabled) or a Redis (cluster mode enabled) replication group.

and for `delete_replication_group`,

> Deletes an existing replication group. By default, this operation deletes the entire replication group, including the primary/primaries and all of the read replicas. If the replication group has only one primary, you can optionally delete only the read replicas, while retaining the primary by setting RetainPrimaryCluster=true .